# Access Denied when attempting to use Google Maps Geocoding Service with a Console API Key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

**UPDATE:** In an effort to give a more clear question. How do I use the Google Console API key with the Google Maps Geocoding Web Service API? At the moment the request comes back as denied, when I specify the key but even though it failed it is logged in the Google Console API site's reports section.
[image]

---

**Original Question**

I have an existing app that has been modified to start geocoding address at the time they are entered (for use within the app on a Google Map). The volume expected for this is expcted to be within the free offering's limites and does not require a key at this time. However now I have to geocode all of the existing addresses. I have a small windows app (C#) that will loop through them one at a time, request they be geocoded (via https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json) and store the results in the database. However I keep running into the query limit. To help alleviate this I've setup an account on Google API Console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/) so that I get go over the limit and just be billed for the overages.

The problem is in order to do utilize this billing alternative I have to provide a Console API Key to the request, but every time I do so I get a response back with a status of `REQUEST_DENIED`.

My URL looks like this
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043&sensor=false&key=123abc

If I take off the key it works fine, but with it on it fails. Now, I have seen other questions similar to this when looking around but can find no answer to the issue.

I've tried various alternate domains including maps.google.com, maps.googleapis.com and maps-api-ssl.google.com all seem to have the same problem from what I can tell.

Here's what I've been able to find out so far:

- The service is listed in the Google Console API's site as Google Maps API v3, (there is a separate entry for v2) so I don't think it's a problem with keys no longer being mandatory in v3.
- I know the requests are getting through and being correctly logged against this API key because with each failed attempt the request count goes up by one on the Reports tab of the Google APIs Console.
- *I know it's not a problem with it not being accessed via a web page because the Console API explicitly lets you generates keys intended for Server/Service use and you can restrict access to them via IP address, not URL Referrer.
- *I've also verified the parameter syntax as it's outlined on [this page](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#UsingKeys), as are other usage

*These seem to be generic to the Console API system but there is no mention of exceptions to these practices when used for the Google Maps API.

I even tried to contact Google but apparently they don't offer support over the phone (I was hoping to be done with this today but that's not looking likely).

Comment: We are experiencing the same/similar issues attempting to leverage the "Google Maps API v3"...if send/transmit the API key from the console Google rejects "This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key."...but we don't get any failures logged on our console.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this so I'm open to any ideas :-/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the key is not necessary anymore, since it doesn't increase your limit of free geocodings.

It was a legacy of v2, but geocoding API v2 was fully deprecated last March, 8.

If you need to use more than the free limit, I think you must adquire the Enterprise license.

Regards,
Eduardo.

Comment: I had entertained that as a possibility as well, but as I mentioned above, if the API key is a legacy feature of v2 and is not relevant to v3, how do you use a the Google Console API key with the Geocoding Web Service of Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and solved it by enabling the Geocoding API on the Google apis dashboard.  Even though I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3, it still required me to enable the Geocoding API as well.  Make sure you understand the google's quota limits and billing system before enabling any API access.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Late to this answer, but just in case anyone else has issue. Billing needs to be setup first and like Dylan said you also have to enable Geocoding API(this got me). At least I did for my locations app that shows multiple store location addresses.

Comment: My original question isn't really valid any more. To my knowledge, all access to Google APIs now requires an API Key, period. Even if you expect/know you're within the limits for the free tier. It also requires your billing information be setup so that in the event that you MIGHT surpass the free tier, you are billed automatically and operation continues as normal with no interruption to the users/apps using the API access.